# Table source code empty when using DataTables server side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using DataTables with server side processing.

I notice that if my table shows results, for example 100 rows then these rows are not shown in HTML source hence affecting SEO.

How do I get DataTables server side processing to update HTML source rather than showing an empty table?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should create a socalled snapshot to make google "happy". Simply have a static table in your html / template with the first 100 rows (or whatever you need)

Comment: @davidkonrad Ok. So the answer here is 'it's not possible', right?

Comment: Well, not as a builtin functionality or by a dedicated plugin for dataTables. But are you completely sure that google are not indexing the content? You can use webmastertools and the Fetch as Google tool ... Google has become increasingly better to index content generated by javascript (as a serverside jQuery dataTables) so perhaps you are worrying for nothing.